# gcloud nodejs createDataset: How to set data location?

Tags: gcloud-node

When I create a dataset using the expression below, it commits but doesn't set any location and when I try to copy data from other dataset I have an error because they in different locations: source: EU, destination: US.

```
bigquery.createDataset('my-dataset', function(err, dataset, apiResponse) {});
```

I didn't find anything in the docs https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.24.1/bigquery?method=createDataset

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an oops on our part when writing the `createDataset` code. Sorry about that; I'll try to get it out for the next release.

(Issue opened at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/941)

Comment: Released! https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/releases/tag/v0.25.0